# Microsoft Outlook for Mac - View Mailbox size

Tags: email, ms-office

We switched from Lotus Notes 8.5.3 and we now use Microsoft Outlook 2011 for Mac in my office. Lotus Notes used to show the size of the mailbox (check the image below). Is it possible to show the mailbox size like this in Outlook? I know how to check the size of the mailbox by right clicking it and seeing Folder properties. But if we have this kind of a feature, it would be convenient.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, Outlook:Mac 2011 doesn't make it possible for you to view your mailbox size at all times in the UI.  The method that you've found of viewing it via the Folder Properties is the only method.

If this is important to you, you should submit feedback to Microsoft.  In Outlook, go to Help -> Send Feedback About Outlook.  Tell them exactly what you want, why you want it, and how it impacts you to not have it.  Be verbose -- the better of a case that you can make, the higher the chance is that your feedback will be given due consideration.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will do that. Any mail interface displays the size of the mailbox these days.